# retrieve data from left table when condition is not met

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I have a scenario where I have to join two tables and want to retrieve data from left table when condition does not meet.

Example:
table1:

```
ID   code  itemsequence
0001  1      1
0001  1      2
0001  2      1
0001  2      2
0001  3      1
0002  null   1
```

table 2:

```
ID   code  outcomeID sequence   itemsequence
0001  1      0001     1             1
0001  1      0004     4             2
0001  2      0002     2             1
0001  2      0005     5             2
0001  3      0003     3             1
0002  null   0001     1             1
```

When I do below select ,I get 6 rows but has t2.sequence which is NULL for ID==002.this is correct

```
  select * from table1 t1
   LEFT join table2 t2
    on t2.Id=t1.ID and t1.itemsequence=t2.itemsequence and t2.code=t1.code
```

but I would like to have have sequence value in spite the condition fails. I want this sequence value for respective ID for further calculations in my project. 
Can we do this ?
any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [ISNULL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx)

> Replaces NULL with the specified replacement value.

```
and ISNULL(t2.code,-1)=ISNULL(t1.code,-1)
```

Or [COALESCE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx)

> Evaluates the arguments in order and returns the current value of the first expression that initially does not evaluate to NULL.

```
and COALESCE(t2.code,-1)=COALESCE(t1.code,-1)
```

To work this out.

NOTE: Both statement will change `NULL` to `-1` so you can do proper join. If you got few columns with same `ID` with `NULL` in `code` there will be effect of CROSS JOIN on this rows.

Comment: My pleasure! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Or you can add one more condition for NULL values `t2.code IS NULL AND t1.code IS NULL`

```
AND t1.itemsequence=t2.itemsequence AND 
   ( t2.code = t1.code OR (t2.code IS NULL AND t1.code IS NULL))
```